# When I call the thread after using a stop variable, it doesn't run . Can somebody please point out the error in the code?

Tags: java, thread-safety

## This is the class Portfolio:

```
public class Portfolio extends Thread {
    private volatile Thread stopMe= Thread.currentThread();
            
    public Portfolio(String name) {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void stopMe(){
        stopMe= null;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(stopMe== Thread.currentThread()){
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            //sleep(700);   
            System.out.println("You have " +(500+i)+ " shares of IBM");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+e.toString());
        }}
    }

    
}
```

## This is where I call the thread

```
public class TestThreads {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MarketNews mn= new MarketNews("Market News");
        mn.start();
        //mn.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY+1);
        //mn.interrupt();
        mn.isAlive();       
        Portfolio p= new Portfolio("Portfolio data");
        p.start();
    //  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().interrupted());
        System.out.println("TestThreads is finished");
        
    }

}
```

## I have called p.start(), but it doesn't seem to work .The code works fine when I remove the stopMe variable.

Comment: Do you have a debugger?  Why can you not break on the 'while' line and inspect stopMe?  Declare one more int to store the result from currentThread() and you would have been there.

Comment: @MartinJames I get the following message when I debug :
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:820]

Comment: Just please, why not use a boolean flag to stop your thread, like everyone else? What's the point of using a reference to a thread, shooting yourself in the foot like you are doing right now?

Comment: @Deepakbehera - me neither :(  Marko has a point about the boolean flag. If nothing else, it saves a kernel call on every loop!

Answer (score 5):

When you run:

```
Portfolio p= new Portfolio("Portfolio data");
```

stopMe is the "main" thread (the current one)

then

```
p.start()
```

you start a new one, so stopMe is different from that thread, and the "run" function from portfolio will stop directly

Comment: You beat me, so +1.  Constructor runs on constructing thread, (as would have been immediately obvious if the OP had used a debugger).

Comment: stopMe is just a volatile variable which I am using to stop a thread.

Comment: @Deepakbehera And it is working perfectly. It is stopping the thread. If you didn't want it stopped yet, it must have the wrong value. Don't use Thread references for this, use a Boolean.